# How to prove P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B|A′)P(A′)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing

What i have tried so far:
given P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B)

P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B) = P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B|A′)P(A′)

P(B) - P(A ∩ B) = P(B|A′)P(A′)

I dont know how to continue, maybe my approach is entirely wrong :c

Comment: Just keep in mind the definition of conditional probabilities: $P(B|A')=\frac{P(B\cup A')}{P(A')}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, it just gets a bit sidetracked in the middle. Your result can be proved as follows:

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
$$=P(A)+[P(A\cap B)+P(A'\cap B)]-P(A\cap B)$$
$$=P(A)+P(A'\cap B)$$
$$=P(A)+\frac{P(A'\cap B)}{P(A')}P(A')$$
$$=P(A)+P(B\mid A')P(A')$$

Comment: I know its right, but cant seem to phrase why the P(A′∩B) =P(B∣A′)P(A′). Could you please explain how did you get there?

Comment: @HarshDua I added a line to my solution. It should be clear now from the definition of conditional probability?